# How to get date with 00:00:00 timestamp

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the date in this format:

```
Thu Nov 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But I'm getting in this format:

```
Thu Nov 01 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How can I get the desired output?

this is what I tried:

```
new Date (item.expDate+ 'T00:00:00Z');
```

Comment: what code are you using to get the first result?

Comment: because as far as I know you should be able to use `new Date(year, month, date, 0,0,0)` to set the hour/min/seconds to zero for the given values `year, month, date` in your code

Comment: you can also set the hour/minute/seconds after creation like so `var d = new Date(); d.setHours(0,0,0)`

Comment: `setHours` worked. ! thanks @Jhecht

Comment: @Jhecht do u know any reason why its taking by default `5:30` instead of `zero`

Comment: I believe it defaults to the current time upon creation but I can't be sure of that without looking it up

Comment: [a helpful link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: @Mrworldwide—you're setting the time to 00:00:00 UTC but the string is local, so it's offset by the host timezone offset (which is +0530 apparently). BTW, if *item.expDate* is in YYYY-MM-DD format, it will be parsed as UTC anyway (a rather silly idiosyncrasy of ECMAScript), adding "T00:00:00Z" does nothing useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and use `setHours`, `setMinutes`, and `setSeconds` to set the hours, minutes, and seconds to `0`.

```js
var d = new Date;
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
console.log(d);
```

This could be combined into one [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) call.

```js
var d = new Date;
d.setHours(0, 0, 0); // arguments are hours, minutes, seconds
console.log(d.toString());
```

You can also just use the `Date` constructor like this:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

```js
console.log(new Date(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0));
```